# How to update column name from _Contactkey to Contactkey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

Any one please help me to update column name from _ContactKey to ContactKey i.e removing the _(underscore) through query activity in marketing cloud.

Thanks,
Rajesh

Comment: Could you provide some background info? From where are you querying (which tool) and how does your query look like?

Comment: Sounds like a Synchronized Data Extension? I know those always include a _ContactKey field. It's a system generated field that can't be updated, not sure why you would need / want to either.

Answer (score 1):

In your Query Activity, you will need to use an [SQL alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) to rename the column heading to match the ContactKey field in your target Data Extension. For example:

```
SELECT _ContactKey AS ContactKey,
Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM DataExtensionName
```

Replace `FieldN` with the other fields required in your query.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply. Below is the query I tried 
select id,_contactkey,_contactkey as contactkey from user_salesforce 

and I select the target as user_salesforce and update type as Update.


but, it showing error like "Error saving the Query field.The Target Data Extension must have at least one primary key field."

Please help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Query activities that use an update type require one or more primary keys in the target Data Extension. Edit the target Data Extension and assign a field (or fields) as a primary key, where the field is unique. For example if the `contactkey` field will always be a unique value in your Data Extension, then make that a primary key. Alternatively, change your query type to Overwrite as this will not require a primary key in your target Data Extension.

Comment: Synchronized Data Extensions  properties not able to edit. Need to ask for support team?

Comment: Oh, you didn't say it was a Synchronized Data Extension. I'll have to check but I'm pretty sure you can't add records to Synchronized Data Extensions. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to upload data back to Sales Cloud?

Comment: I would need to use a query activity and change the column name of _Contactkey to an alias as something that does not start with an underscore to allow the import to work properly.